# Binding static IP settings

Tags: c#, windows-ce, tcp

I'm trying to configure a device's TCP/IP settings via registries but i can't seem to get it to work without a soft reboot.

I've been scouring Google for an answer and found that the way to do it is to pinvoke DeviceIoControl().

I've looked at the registries and they are definitely changing to the ones i want, I can't get DeviceIoControl() to return anything except 0 (fail) and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFile", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFLagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint dwIoControlCode,  ref string lpInBuffer, int nInBufferSize, out string lpOutBuffer, int nOutBufferSize, ref int lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "CloseHandle", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

public static void SetTCPIP()
{
    RegistryKey baseKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
    string subKey = @"Comm\FEC1\Parms\TcpIp";
    string enableDhcpKey = "EnableDHCP";
    string gatewayKey = "DefaultGateway";
    string ipAddressKey = "IpAddress";
    string subnetMaskKey = "Subnetmask";
    string ipAddress = "192.168.8.100";
    string subnetMask = "255.255.255.0";
    string gateway = "192.168.8.1";

    WriteReg(baseKey, subKey, enableDhcpKey, 0);
    WriteRegMultiString(baseKey, subKey, ipAddressKey, ipAddress);
    WriteRegMultiString(baseKey, subKey, gatewayKey, gateway);
    WriteRegMultiString(baseKey, subKey, subnetMaskKey, subnetMask);
    CommitLocalMachineRegistry(); //RegFlushKey()
    BindAdapter();
}

private static void BindAdapter()
{
    const uint genericRead = 0x80000000;
    const uint genericWrite = 0x40000000;
    const int IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER = 0x17002E;
    const int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    const string NI = @"NDS0:";
    //Open the Handle to Rebind the Network Adapter
    IntPtr hNdis = CreateFile(NI, genericRead | genericWrite, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (hNdis == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"+hNdis);
    }
    string Adapter = "FEC1\0";
    string OutBuffer = "";
    int bytesReturned = 0;
    //Rebind the Network Adapter
    int check = DeviceIoControl(hNdis, IOCTL_NDIS_REBIND_ADAPTER,  ref Adapter, Adapter.Length,
        out OutBuffer, 0, ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (check==0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
    //Close the Handle
    CloseHandle(hNdis);
}
```

I've tried getting more info on the issue using GetLastWin32Error() but it's returning 0 as well

Edit (couldn't add comment)
i've tried having Adapter = "FEC1\0\0" and I've also tried marshalling as a StringBuilder with no luck
Edit 2
Registries are HIVE based, so changes persist after a reboot.

Comment: Minor detail and probably not the issue, CreateFile returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (0xFFFFFFFF) on error, not zero.

Comment: Another thing, `Adapter` is a multi-string, i.e. each string must be terminated with NUL, and the multi-string itself must have an additional NUL appended, so `Adapter` should be initialized to "FEC1\0\0", and the length passed to `DeviceIoControl` must include both NUL's

Comment: Windows owns the devices so you cannot change without rebooting.  The change gets made before Windows gets started.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've tried initialising Adapter as "FEC1\0\0" and I've also tried marshalling it as StringBuilder with no result.